# How to parse form-data from curl in Ruby

Tags: ruby, curl, multipartform-data

I'm building a lambda function that needs to receive several parameters, including eventually files.

```
curl -v -H "Authorization: blah" -F "index_name=test" -F "document=@./spec/fixtures/config/indexes/video.json" -X POST https://blah.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/index_document
```

I can see from inside my `event['body']` that I'm receiving my data, but I can't find a way to parse the data and using Rack feels a bit weird.

```
<--------------------------298624d5b63e53bf
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="index_name"

test
--------------------------298624d5b63e53bf
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="document"; filename="video.json"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "number_of_shards": 5
    }, ...
```

Is there any other way to have my data back in an orderly fashion, like:

```
>>> event['body']['index_name']
"test"
```

Comment: can you give an example of the data you're getting back?

Comment: Just updated. It's actually the body of a multipart request, no big surprise.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you have a look at the [curb ruby gem](https://github.com/taf2/curb)